# A necessary condition for constant functions via the $\nabla$ operator

Tags: multivariable-calculus, derivatives

Let $f:\mathbb{R}^2\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be differentiable and for any point in the open unit disc about the origin, we have $\nabla f(x)=0$. Show $f$ is the constant function in this region.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $a$ and $b$ two arbitrary points  in the open unit disc $D$ about the origin and $S=\{a+t(b-a): t \in [0,1]\}$. Then $ S \subseteq D$.

The Mean value theorem gives some $c \in S$ such that

$$f(b)-f(a)=(b-a)*\nabla f(c)=0.$$

( $*$ denotes the inner product on $\mathbb R^2$). It follws that $f(b)=f(a)$